# Simple Mathematics in Shell/Bash (RAM Calculation)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

The following code gets the amount of RAM

```
number=$(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2;}')
```

Now, I want to divide this number by e.g. 2048. But how can I solve this in the same line? At the end, I need a number like 2.8 (one digit after point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in same `awk` as

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{ printf "%0.1f\n", $1/2048;}'
```

Read more about `GNU awk` [`format-modifiers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html). Refer the sub-section under `.prec`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need *grep* at all. AWK is powerful enough to search for the patterns:

```
number=$(awk '/^MemTotal:/ {printf("%.1f", $2 / 2048)}' /proc/meminfo)
```